# jquery <th> bgcolor match with tbody

Tags: jquery

I have the below table. I am trying to get tbody column bgcolors matching with theader bg colors.

Can you please help , as I am not able to achieve this?

Thanks and Regards,

> ```
> <table id="one" border="1">  <thead>  <tr>
>  <th style="background-color:Lime">Header 1</th>
>  <th>Header 2</th>  </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>  <tr>
>  <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
>  <td>row 1, cell 2</td>  </tr>  <tr>
>  <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
>  <td>row 2, cell 2</td>  </tr>  </tbody>  </table>   
>  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>      $(document).ready(function () {
>
>          $('#one thead tr th').each(function () {
>
>              var col1 = $(this).css("background-color");
>              var index = $(this).closest("th").prevAll("th").length;
>
>              assigncolr(col1, index);
>          });
>      });
>
>     function assigncolr(col,index){   $('#one tbody tr').each(function () {
>     $(this).find('td :nth-child(' + index + ')').css("background-color", col);
>
>
>         }
>           )
>               };
>
>  </script>
> ```

Comment: I want to make only the td's matching to th. In the above example, i want only 1st column to be of lime color thanks,

Comment: The accepted answer (obviously) fixes the problem, but you can further simplify your code given that `.each()` gives you the index of the current element so you don't need to calculate it yourself. (Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/xpchG/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit shorter and simpler - http://jsfiddle.net/9X4FP/1/

```
var cols = $("th").length;

$("tbody td").each(function() {
    var order = $("td").index(this) % cols;
    var color = $("th:eq(" + order + ")").css("background-color");

    $(this).css("background-color", color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/): "*Because jQuery's implementation of :nth-child(n) is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1.*"

The second problem is the space () between `td` and `nth-child` in your selector. You'll need to eliminate that.

Change:

```
$(this).find('td :nth-child(' + index + ')').css("background-color", col);
```

to:

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').css("background-color", col);
```

This should fix the problem.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WNscb/